# Import Huggingface Transformers offline

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers, huggingface

I have downloaded the library locally and the models I want to use offline because of network restrictions.
I have already used them following the same process as below successfully.

But this time (not knowing what changed), while running this:

```py
!export TRANSFORMERS_OFFLINE=1

sys.path.append('/home/shared/Libraries/transformers-main/src/')
from transformers import BertTokenizer, BertModel
sys.path.append('/home/shared/Libraries/sentence-transformers-master/')
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer
```

I have the following error:

```py
File /home/shared/Libraries/transformers-main/src/transformers/__init__.py:26
     23 from typing import TYPE_CHECKING
     25 # Check the dependencies satisfy the minimal versions required.
---> 26 from . import dependency_versions_check
     27 from .utils import (
     28     OptionalDependencyNotAvailable,
     29     _LazyModule,
   (...)
     46     logging,
     47 )
     50 logger = logging.get_logger(__name__)  # pylint: disable=invalid-name

File /home/shared/Libraries/transformers-main/src/transformers/dependency_versions_check.py:16
      1 # Copyright 2020 The HuggingFace Team. All rights reserved.
      2 #
      3 # Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
   (...)
     12 # See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
     13 # limitations under the License.
     15 from .dependency_versions_table import deps
---> 16 from .utils.versions import require_version, require_version_core
     19 # define which module versions we always want to check at run time
     20 # (usually the ones defined in `install_requires` in setup.py)
     21 #
     22 # order specific notes:
     23 # - tqdm must be checked before tokenizers
     25 pkgs_to_check_at_runtime = [
     26     "python",
     27     "tqdm",
   (...)
     37     "pyyaml",
     38 ]

File /home/shared/Libraries/transformers-main/src/transformers/utils/__init__.py:18
      1 #!/usr/bin/env python
      2 # coding=utf-8
      3 
   (...)
     15 # See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
     16 # limitations under the License.
---> 18 from huggingface_hub import get_full_repo_name  # for backward compatibility
     19 from packaging import version
     21 from .. import __version__

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'huggingface_hub'
```

Same for the import of the SentenceTransformer.
Because I am working offline, I expect to not use the `huggingface_hub`. I also tried to add the offline dataset variable to true.

I can provide more informations if needed.

Comment: I think you still need the package to be installed, its a dependency iirc therefore the error, even if it is not actively needed. I do not know how much of the hub is needed, so it might only be a minor design flaw for this edge case. Maybe raise a Github Issue instead.